# How to get average value according their value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get result of data and their hole average, according to their value, example :

```
select sum(rank) as value,area from temp GROUP BY area
```

```
value | Area
------+-------
15    | East
54    | North
49    | South
35    | West
```

but I want to their total avg like

```
value | Area  | Average
------+-------+---------
49    | East  | 40
15    | North | 40
56    | South | 40
40    | West  | 40
```

How I can get these ? plz help

Comment: If I also needed each value and area, I expect I would delegate averaging to the server script connecting to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery.  Does this give you the results you want?

```
select x.value, t.area
from temp t cross join
     (select sum(rank) / count(distinct area) as value from temp) x
group by t.area, x.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

`select sum(rank) as value, area, avg(value) from temp GROUP BY area`